# tsc not compiling all js files

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm having an issue compiling all the typescript files + javascript files into javascript files.
it's not compiling all the javascript files to the dist folder.

here is the command I run:
`rm -rf ./dist && tsc -p . && node ./dist/server.js`

and I get this error:
`Unhandled rejection Error: Cannot find module './email-service'`
then I went to the folder `email-service` and I can't find the `index.js` file in there, it wasn't compiled.

here is my tsconfig file:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./dist",                    
        "rootDir": ".",                          
        "module": "commonjs",                   
        "target": "es6",                        
        "lib": ["dom", "es6"],                   
        "sourceMap": true,                 
        "checkJs": false,                      
        "allowJs": true,                         
        "moduleResolution": "node",          
        "noEmit": false,                         
        "baseUrl": "./src",                      
        "strict": true,                          
        "esModuleInterop": true,                
        "resolveJsonModule": true,               
        "isolatedModules": true,                  
        "importHelpers": true,                   
        "declaration": true,                      
        "strictPropertyInitialization": false,    
        "alwaysStrict": true,                  
        "paths": {                                
            "~/*": ["*"]
        },
    },
    "include": [ "*.js", "*.ts", "*.json"],      
    "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist"]    
}
```

node version: 10.16.1

Folder Structure :

```
.
├── tsconfig.json
├── _src
│   └──_ email-service
│      └── index.js (missing)
├── _dist
│   └──_src
│      └──_ email-service
│         └── index.js
```

any idea whats the issue?

Comment: The error relates to the source files in `./src`.  You have a reference in some module to `./email-service` and that path is not resolving to a ts/js file.  Remember that paths are generally relative to where they are referred too, and not to `rootDir` (but your configured module resolution might alter that behaviour)

Comment: thanks for the response :) 
but I can't see the file (email-service/index.js) in the dist folder, it wasn't compiled

Comment: Again, its a source file that is missing (or path incorrect).  You won't have a dist file because the source is missing.

Comment: the source file is not missing, and the relative path is correct, on the same folder into email-service folder should be index.js file.
when I look in the regular email-service folder vs the dist email-service folder 
I can see few files are missing (index.js, and file with kebab_case file names)

Comment: I don't think that TSC will process non `.ts` files, there is nothing for it to do.  [This might explain further](https://vccolombo.github.io/blog/tsc-how-to-copy-non-typescript-files-when-building/), the `allowJs` option might be want you are looking for

Comment: is does, few js files were compiled
allowJs is set to true

Comment: Perhaps you can show the directory structure?

Comment: folder structructure added to the question :)

Comment: I did mean for you to include more of the other files so that we might be able to spot if there is any reason.  As it is, you're saying that there is a missing source file, but one in dist.  Please try to be clear.

Comment: the source file is not missing, as I said
the file that is missing is the file that should be generated in the dist/email-service folder

Comment: `│      └── index.js (missing)`.  You are saying one thing and showing another in your question.  If you are saying that another index.js is being correctly transformed to `dist`, but not this one, then there must be some difference in how the files are being processed, but you aren't illustrating clearly what those differences might be.

Comment: this file is missing from the dist, as I wrote next to it

Comment: Ok, you quite literally have the word ‘missing’ on the src branch where you show the folder structure. I understand that you are saying the dist file isn’t being generated, but you are shoeing contradictory information and not the additional information that might help anyone answer your question. I’m going to leave you to it now.